# How to insert multi line text from .csv file to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

the problem i'm facing is as follows
In CSV file in one column i'm having a text which is in multiple line format, how to insert that same text with multi line indent preserved into sqlite database.

For example
**Id  Column1  Column2**
 1      Hello        this is
                     multi line 
                     text to be 
                     inserted into database

Comment: @KlingKlang i'm able to import csv file to sqlite successfully,but the problem is In one of the field i'm having some 8 to 10 lines.for new lines i've tried with \n,"\n",\r\n,"\r\n" but when parsed those lines are not inserting in multiple line in single column..instead value in db is like this this is first line n this is second line n this is third line

Comment: Unclear. Are all the lines inserted in a single row or are they inserted on different rows? You have to understand that in a CSV file the newline character is the **row terminator**.

Comment: the issue is solved.thank you for your response @KlingKlang

Comment: Then you should post the answer and accept it, in order to remove this post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Comment: please may i know the reason for down voting my question

Comment: Because this is **not** a code-request site.

Comment: @KlingKlang i've searched the site and tried the answers given but unable to get the result i needed. Later i got the desired result,now i want to add answer how can i do that,can you please suggest me

Comment: Who stops you from adding your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiline fields in csv you need to enclose them in double quotes:

```
field1,"this is first line  
this is second line  
this is third line",field3
```

Double quotes inside those fields should be escaped with another double quote:

```
field1,"this is first line  
24"" monitor
this is third line",field3
```

Comment: yes i've did like this in .csv file.Then my problem solved